# PHP remove array inside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, unset

so I am trying to remove array in if statement inside foreach loop...

```
<?php
        foreach ($politics as $tag => $key):?>


        <?php    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
                    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
                    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
                        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                    } else {
                        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                      }
                      $vienodas = "SELECT * FROM pol WHERE (politikas = '$Veryga' AND ip = '$ip')";
                      $vienodasres = mysqli_query($conn, $vienodas);
                     if ( mysqli_num_rows($vienodasres) > 0){
                         //IT DOESN'T WORK 
                         unset($politics[$tag]);
                         //IT DOESN'T WORK 
                     }
                      ?>
 <div class="mySlides">
<?php $Veryga= $key['vardas'];
 $Veryga2 = str_replace(' ', '', $Veryga);
 ?>
  <div <?php echo 'id="'.$Veryga2.'"'; ?> class="politikai">

<..Not important code..>



  </div>
  <?php
  endforeach; ?>
```

It doesn't want to work, I was trying to do it, the if statement just checks if there are lines which is equal to user IP and the slide which they are

Comment: In the first line why is there a colon?

Comment: Because there is html code inside, and it works and at the and i close foreach loop with endforeach, this is instead of curly brackets :)

Comment: @Jessedegans It's a alternative syntax for control structures.  I prefer to use curly braces.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the value and key elements around the wrong way it should be defined like this.

```
foreach ($politics as $key => $tag):
    unset($politics[$key]);
```

Comment: though this shouldn't matter for the code execution

Comment: @ikdekker it won't matter but it's incorrectly named and is misleading.

Comment: So where should I put if statement?

Comment: @JonasTamoševičius The if statement is correctly nested but what does mysqli_query return?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz  It returns name and ip, so if there are lines in table where politics (names) is equal to the key and IP from which they have they already voted for that person :)

Comment: @JonasTamoševičius my question is what value is mysqli_num_rows() returning?  When you output the value is it greater than 0 ?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz It returns 1, because there already is one row like this in my database, so I need to find the way on how to unset array after that so it wouldn't show for the user again :)

Answer (score 0):

you're not accessing that `$politics` array-element later, so it is unset, but the control flow continues inside the element.
if you'd like to prevent the output use a `continue;` statement at that point.

Comment: I believe so too. But then i'd expect him to want to skip only when there is no results from the database. Still probably the right answer

Comment: Where to put that statement exactly? :)

Comment: where you unset the element, if i understood your intent correctly ;) and if you plan to make this code available somewhere in the net - please have a look into prepared statements, as you have a wide open sql injection vector sitting there!

Comment: check the amount of returned lines & if the condition is met (and the statements are executed). -> debug output or attached debugger and step-through.

Comment: From PHP's help: `The behaviour of mysqli_num_rows() depends on whether buffered or unbuffered result sets are being used. For unbuffered result sets, mysqli_num_rows() will not return the correct number of rows until all the rows in the result have been retrieved. ` so please check again if the value is really what you expect it to be.